How to display only the first 2 words of a post title
I am learning WP and want to display only the first two words of a post title to the user. For the end user only the first two words of the Post title (H1 class) should be shown but source should have the full title for SEO. For example, if Post title is "Beef Burger - grilled, pan, mustard etc" and I only want to display "Beef Burger" to the end user on all pages - Blog, Archive, custom page with query blocks.
Many threads have offered some solution but they are from years ago. Is there any solution in 2024 as technology might have advanced? I thought this could be done in css but looks like it can't be done. I used ChatGPT to generate some code (code listed below) and it did and instruction was to paste that code in the 'functions.php" file but as I have learned that might get cleared up when the theme gets updated. After much digging around I came across 'Code Snippets'. No idea how to paste the code ChatGPT gave in Code Snippets and maek it work. And read somewhere that the WP Twenty Twenty Four theme doesn't use the functions.php file.
Using the Twenty Twenty Four theme.
Thanks,
Prad
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php
            // Fetch the post title
            $post_title = get_the_title();

            // Split the title into an array of words
            $words = explode(' ', $post_title);

            // Get the first two words
            $first_two_words = implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, 2));

            // Display the first two words
            echo '<h1 class="entry-title short-title">' . esc_html($first_two_words) . '</h1>';

            // Display the full title, hidden
            echo '<h1 class="entry-title full-title" style="display: none;">' . esc_html($post_title) . '</h1>';
            ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <footer class="entry-footer">
            <?php yourtheme_entry_footer(); ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
    </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

    <?php
    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
        comments_template();
    endif;

endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>

</main><!-- #main -->


```
Edit:
Thanks for the comments indicating that this method is not SEO friendly. I did go through the discussion here - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css
My use case is not to spam. I just want to limit the post title when displayed in a grid, so it looks cleaner. The post will still have the title. I found an example of something similar I want to achieve - IMDB page https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0881631/ There are different sections for Personal details where they are displaying the text but also adding additional and relevant text for SEO.
How can I achieve this on 2024 block theme?

I'm not sure that doing that will help you. search engines know this kind of tinkering for years and that can also disfavour your website. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css

for you question about the theme, you can create a child theme to hold customisations when the parent theme is updated : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

you're much more likely to get SEO penalties instead, this might have worked in the early 2000's but search engines caught on to this years ago. Also the twenty twentyfour theme isn't a PHP theme it's a block theme. ChatGPT was also incorrect to suggest putting that into functions.php as that would put a post loop at the top of every request, even admin and AJAX requests

I am thinking of doing it by taking the Title block code, adding a function to only display the first 2 words and creating a new block. SO wherever I need this, Instead of the default Title block, I can use this modified block.
I'd appreciate if someone can point me to some literature or videos which can show me how to take the Title code from github and build a block.

You can use "wp_trim_words" function for this case.
Exam: To display the first two words.

echo esc_html(wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 2, '' ) );

Use this code within your H1 tag.
You can control the number of words you want to show in the title by changing the second parameter of the function "wp_trim_words" to know more about this function visit wordpress.org

Thanks. However, when I said I am learning WP, I meant as an end user. I am not a developer. How do I do this? I thought Block Editor would be easy and it is for the most part but I guess for some customizations, development skill is needed.
